# Infinite loop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I have a loop where I load a json object and I want that the data from the json file will showing in my leaflet map in real time.
When I add values in the json file, jsonData.length show me the updated lenght, but the loop doesn't increment the variable j.
How is it possible to increment the variable j, after new values was added to the json file?

```
function Loop() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        load_js();
        jsonData=loadJSON();  //load JSON Data

        lat = jsonData[j];
        lon = jsonData[j+1];

        var id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
        jdl = jsonData.length;
        mapUpdater("" + id, lat, lon);


        if (j < jsonData.length) {
            j=j+2;
        }

        Loop();

    }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: instead of recursive function just use setInterval

Comment: First of all you have to call the function. You should put `Loop();` outside the function.

Comment: Technically, the infinite loop works.

Comment: You know you'll run out of memory doing this, right?

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson why would they?

Comment: They'll stackoverflow if it runs enough times.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson they won't. Every call would be run with its own stack trace.

Comment: How does each stack trace not take up extra memory?

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson how having **just one stack trace** of 2 function calls deep would make any problem for a runtime?

Comment: You're misunderstanding what I misunderstood. I'm wrong, okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys.
Maybe I didn't elaborated my problem enough.

I found the problem on my own.
I think the if condition was the problem.

I think the array was out of range. 
The answer to this problem was this:

I changed this:

```
if (j < jsonData.length) {
            j=j+2;
        }
```

to this:

```
if (j < jsonData.length-2) {
            j=j+2;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the scope of j. Or you can add j to argument of Loop function.

```
function Loop(j) {
  if (j === undefined)
    j = 0;
  setTimeout(function() {

    load_js();
    jsonData = loadJSON(); //load JSON Data

    lat = jsonData[j];
    lon = jsonData[j + 1];

    var id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
    jdl = jsonData.length;
    mapUpdater("" + id, lat, lon);


    if (j < jsonData.length) {
      j = j + 2;
    }

    Loop(j);

  }, 1000)
}
Loop();
```

Comment: `if(!j)` {} would be faster.